# Is quantum torus a principal ideal domain?

Tags: principal-ideal-domains

For a quantum torus $C_q[x_1^{\pm1}, ...,x_n^{\pm1}]$ satisfying $x_ix_j=q_{ij}x_jx_i$.

Question: Is this quantum torus a principal ideal domain?

Comment: You had better edit it with LaTeX.

Comment: At the level of generality at which you posed the question the answer is clearly no: take all $q_{ij}$ equal to $1$, so that  you have a commutative ring of Laurent polynomials in $n$ variables. The Krull dimension of such a thing is $n$, which is usually not $1$, which is the Krull dimension of a principal ideal domain which is not a field.

Comment: I like your question, rather to ask further under which condition sit might be a *principal ideal domain*?

Comment: What is a noncommutative principal ideal domain?